# How to get firstChild classname?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using js script to make a dynamic tree view.
I got a `<div class="toggler">` which is just  a div with css style and inside that `<div>`
I created a `<div class="toggler-target">` which is a first child of `toggler` and should appear and disappear by click on that `toggler`.
I don't know why but when I click on `toggler` it doesn't show up.
It worked while my `toggler-target` was placed right after `<div class="toggler">` and i used `<.nextElementSibling.matches>` function.

code:

```js
document.getElementById("todos").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.matches(".todo")) tgt.classList.toggle('active');
    else if (tgt.matches(".toggler") && tgt.firstChild.classList.matches(".toggler-target")) {
      tgt.classList.toggle('active');
      tgt.firstChild.classList.toggle('active')
    } else if (tgt.matches(".toggler")) tgt.classList.toggle('active')
  }

)
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto; text-align: center">
  <div class="todos" id="todos" style="display: inline-block;padding-top: 0px; text-align: left">
    <div class="toggler">Global
      <div class="toggler-target">
        <button class="btn btn-primary fw-light" id="addTaskBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addTaskForm">Add
                    Task
                </button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary fw-light" id="newBranch" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addBranchForm">Create branch
                </button>
        <div class="toggler" th:each="branchDto:${branches}">
          <div class="toggler-target" th:each="branchDto:${branches}">
            <a th:text="${branchDto.getTitle()}"></a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary fw-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addTaskForm">Add
                            Task
                        </button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary fw-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addBranchForm">Create branch
                        </button>
            <form class="btn btn-danger" th:action="@{'/test/branch/{branch_id}'(branch_id=${branchDto.getBranch_id()})}" th:method="delete">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Delete Branch</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="todo" th:each="taskDto:${tasks}">
            <a th:text="${taskDto.getTitle()}">title></a>
            <form class="btn btn-danger" th:action="@{'/test/{id}'(id=${taskDto.getId()})}" th:method="delete">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Delete Task</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: classList has no matches function afaik, you should use contains (without the dot at the beginning)

Comment: You probably want `firstElementChild` rather than `firstChild`, so you skip over text nodes.

Comment: there is a `<div class="toggler"` inside the first `<div class="toggler"`....